# Datepicker in ruby on rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I'm using this gem and followed the instructions to get it working.

https://github.com/derencius/zebra-datepicker-rails

Here is a sreenshot:

[image: screen.png]

As you can see in the picture from the link above I'm able to get the datepicker to work and input the correct date but I've tried everything to be in the "Time Needed" section. Since I'm new to Ruby on Rails and jquery I'm just not familiar enough to make this work as it should.

```
  <tr> 
    <td>*<%= f.label :Time_Needed %>:</td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :TimeNeeded, :id=>"TimeNeeded" %></td> 
  </tr>

<input type="text" class="datepicker"  >

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to attach datepicker to "TimeNeeded" Textbox, please see the jquery code as below:-

Just change your selector to as id of TimeNeeded textbox so it will get attached to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#TimeNeeded').Zebra_DatePicker();
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this was supposed to be the code that i'm supposed to put in my views. But the $('#TimeNeeded').zebra... you mentioned does not work unfortunately. Once I load my form, the little option to choose the datepicker symbol dissappears. 

<input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' >

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').Zebra_DatePicker();
    </script>